# End of support for Basic Authentication access to Exchange Online APIs for Office 365

Tags: exchange-basicauth

When is the end of support for Basic Authentication access to Exchange Online APIs for Office 365?

Answer (score 1):

**October 13th, 2020**

Taken from this [article](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/end-of-support-for-basic-authentication-access-to-exchange-online-apis-for-office-365-customers/).

Answer (score 0):

The end was supposed to be October 13th, 2020 but it seems to have been postponed due to Covid-19.

Taken from this [article](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/deferred-end-of-support-date-for-basic-authentication-in-exchange-online/)